# How to monitor I/O for a specific file

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, performance-monitoring

In windows server 2008 it is possible to see the top files which consume the most I/O on the filesystem using standard system tools.

How to setup the same counters, but in reverse - I would like to have a graph that shows I/O on a specific file?

The purpose of this exercise is to monitor I/O on the SQL Server - here I know which files constitute logs and database files and would like to see how much I/O is used for each of the databases running on the server (so to compare and measure I/O that is gets assigned to each database).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in tool in Windows that allows you to see which files are being written to. I'll let that sink in for a moment before moving on.

You'll want to look for another tool, and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is a good start if not the only tool you'll need.

***HOWEVER***, what you probably want to do is monitor the database performance from within SQL Server itself. For example, this little beauty:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL)
```

Among many other performance monitoring capabilities within SQL Server itself.